# The tkinter module uses text i want to save the value of text2 in a .txt file in a language translator when text 2 uses the Text module of tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

#translation
def translate_now():

```
      text_=text1.get(1.0,END)
      t1=Translator()
      trans_text=t1.translate(text_,src=combo1.get(),dest=combo2.get())
      trans_text=trans_text.text

      text2.delete(1.0,END)
      text2.insert(END,trans_text)
```

Comment: It seems like this could be answered by reading existing [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). It's not clear why you need our help.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try to provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As  it stands, it is unclear what your problem is and why you need help.

Comment: @BryanOakley  i have already tried that the thing is text2 over here is not an indivdual object it is a string that uses a the text module in tkinter so the fileout.write is not working on this code i have already tried what you have suggested maybe if i send the whole code u can understand

Comment: That comment is hard to understand. You say text2 isn't an individual object and that it is a string.  Strings in python are objects, but you are treating it like an instance of `Text`, which is also an object. Also, you mention the text module in tkinter but tkinter doesn't have a text module. There is a `Text` class, however.  We can't help debug code if you don't provide a complete [mcve]. It's impossible for us to know what `text2` really is based on the information you've supplied.

Comment: @BryanOakley is it possible we could exchange mail ids or something cuz i really need help for this assignment